# Cayley Graph of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs

As the title suggest, I'm interested in depicting (if possible) the Cayley graph of the special linear group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

I know one has to start with a presentation of the group so $$SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) =\langle x,y \mid x^4=1 , x^2=y^3\rangle$$ but then stuff start to become really messy, I mean I start with the point representing the neutral element, and the presentation suggests me that I have a square attached to it by one of its vertices since $x^4=1$. Now by the fact that $y^3=x^2$ I can depict the diagonal from the identity to the vertex $x^2$ as the line $1-y-y^2-y^3=x^2$

But then how to go on? Is there a smarter way? are there some picture of it?

Comment: I would start by drawing the Cayley graph of the quotient group by $\langle x^2 \rangle$ which is a free product $C_2*C_3$ and is easy. Then to get the Cayley graph of ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$, replace each vertex with two vertices, where you get from one to the other by $x^2=y^3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'll think about that! thanks for the advice!

Comment: @DerekHolt I think I managed to draw the graph of $C_2\ast C_3$, what is unclear now is what do you mean by replacing each vertex with two vertices. I just add them in a line? (the vertex $x^2$ in the segment $e$ -- $x^2$ becomes $e$--$x$--$x^2$) or what?

Comment: No, he means wherever you see a vertex in $C_2 * C_3$, you erase it and replace it with a pair of vertices connected by $x^2$. You'll also have to erase each edge (connecting two vertices of $C_1 * C_3$) and erase it and replace it by four edges (connecting two pairs of vertices).